# Create SQL queries for SQLite with MFC primitives

Tags: c++, sqlite, mfc

I'm using SQLite to store my program's state. sqlite3_exec() accepts the SQL query as a string. So I have a lot of code that builds such queries by concatenating numerous `CString` instances and a feeling that I'm doing something wrong.

Is there a better way of doing this staying within primitives provided within SQLite and MFC?

Answer (score 1):

[This excellent piece of code](http://sqlite3pp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) provides a nice C++ wrapper around SQLite3. It has a very nice binding methods, which saves a lot of unnecessary lines from your code (in this case, CStrings). Check it out; there's a lot of examples as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to take advantage of the MFC facilites to access the SQLite API in a clearer way.

Due to the fact that the SQLite interface is **C-oriented**, it might be better to **encapsulate the access** with a wrapper C++ class and you might use **normal arrays of chars** and **sprintf** to fill the dynamic values inside this class (though you could go on with CStrings... if you find them clearer).

We, at work, have a class which encapsulates the access and allows us not to have to build any sql statement explicitly.

The example referred by nhaa123 deserves a +1 vote!